# Out-File only if the variable doesn't exist in the file

Tags: powershell, file-io, unique

Goal: Write a variable to a text file ONLY if it doesn't already exist in that text file.

What I'm doing:

```
if (! (Get-Content "C:\historique.txt" | Where-Object {$_ -like $var})) {
    $var | Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath "C:\historique.txt" -Append -Force
}
```

"If the $var is NOT found in the file, Out-File..."

It works, but is this the best / fastest approach? The file won't get really huge but I want it to be as optimal as possible.

Comment: I would create a variable with the content of the text and write it in the end as one instead of adding one line at the time over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-notmatch` regex comparison to see if the file content does not have the wanted string in `$var`, like so:

```
$file = 'C:\historique.txt'
$var  = 'blah'
if ((Get-Content -Path $file -Raw) -notmatch [regex]::Escape($var)) {
    Add-Content -Path $file -Value $var -Encoding Ascii -Force
}
```

Comment: Good one, much appreciated.